# Style CSS is different between browsers

Tags: html, css, browser

i need your help with my css. i made a css/html - gadget in blogger out of my knowledge and i seem to have some problems.

Well as you can see in the code there is a background picture , a picture in front left and text in front right with some links on it. The problem is with the front left picture. In Google Chrome it seems ok on the lines with the text, but if i open web page with firefox, the picture gets some pixels up and the result is that is not in the same line with the text as it has to be.

Here is the Code.

```
    <style>
.boxed {
  border: 0.0em solid ;margin-bottom:3px;margin-top:3px;
background:url(BACKGROUNDIMAGELINK) repeat-x bottom;color:#fff;
}
.boxed:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
.stoiximan {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 0px;}
.mybet {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 -37px;}
.championsbet {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 -74px;}
.novibet {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 -111px;}
.betsonic {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 -148px;}
.netbet {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 -185px;}
.sportingbet {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 -222px;}
.bet8 {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 -259px;}
.vistabet {width:120px; height:37px; background:url(IMG LINK) 0 -296px;}
</style><div class="boxed">
<a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow"><div class="stoiximan" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;" alt="STOIXIMAN"></div>   </a><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">STOIXIMAN</a><br /><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:Open sans;"   >100% έως 50€ Bonus</a>
</div>

<div class="boxed">
<a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow"><div class="mybet" alt="MYBET" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;"></div></a><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">MYBET</a><br /><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:open sans;"   >100% έως 100€ Bonus</a></div>

<div class="boxed">
<a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow"><div class="championsbet" alt="CHAMPIONSBET" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;"></div></a><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">CHAMPIONSBET</a><br /><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:open sans;"   >Bonus 200€</a></div>

<div class="boxed">
 <a target="_blank" link" rel="nofollow"><div class="novibet" alt="NOVIBET" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;"></div></a><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">NOVIBET</a><br /><a target="_blank"  href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:open sans;"   >100% έως 150€ Bonus</a>
</div>

<div class="boxed">
    <a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow"><div class="betsonic" alt="BETSONIC" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;"></div></a><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">BETSONIC</a><br /><a target="_blank"  href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:open sans;"   >100% έως 50€ Bonus</a>
</div>

<div class="boxed">
    <a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow"><div class="netbet" alt="NETBET" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;"></div></a><a target="_blank" href="link" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">NETBET</a><br /><a target="_blank"  href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:open sans;"   >100% έως 100€ Bonus</a>
</div>

<div class="boxed">
    <a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow"><div class="sportingbet" alt="SPORTINGBET" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;"></div></a><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">SPORTINGBET</a><br /><a target="_blank"  href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:open sans;"   >100% έως 100€ Bonus</a>
</div>

<div class="boxed">
    <a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow"><div class="bet8" alt="BET8" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;"></div></a><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">BET8</a><br /><a target="_blank"  href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:open sans;"   >50% Bonus έως 100€</a>
</div>

<div class="boxed">
    <a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow"><div class="vistabet" alt="VISTABET" style="float:left;margin-right: 1em;"></div></a><a target="_blank" href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:#FFf;font-family:open sans;letter-spacing:1px;">VISTABET</a><br /><a target="_blank"  href="link" rel="nofollow" style="font-weight:normal;color:white;font-family:open sans;"   >100% Bonus έως 100€</a>
</div>
```

Here is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fn4pgvjL/ to see what i mean...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You shouldnt use inline styles. Certainly not THIS MUCH. I'm not reading that.

Comment: sorry iam a newbie...thats why i post this here so that you can advice or help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things will fix what I'm guessing is the problem. First, set overflow on `.boxed` to force it to contain its child elements:

```
.boxed {overflow: hidden; /* or 'auto' */ }
```

Then, reduce the font size so Firefox doesn't make it too large, which pushed down the box and creates a gap under the images:

```
.boxed {font-size: 14px; /* largest that seemed to work in Firefox */ }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fn4pgvjL/2/)

Do this in a new or existing embedded `style` tag, *not* with inline styles on the elements:

```
<style>
.boxed {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
```

---

To make your code cleaner, use styles in the same `style` tag that apply to all elements in the page, like so:

```
<style>
.boxed {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.boxed a {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
    font-family: "open sans", arial, sans-serif;
}
.boxed a div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , iam trying to fix it from beginning.. i will let you know as soos as it works

Comment: did everything you said but still firefox is showing things different.
here is code: http://jsfiddle.net/fn4pgvjL/3/
here is blog http://bit.ly/1bKFFbb , its right on the sidebar..

could it be the whole code faults?

Comment: it worked isherwood!!! problem was that  font-size: 14px; should have been on .boxed a not on .boxed. i added !important after this and now is ok! thanks for the answer and the help!